# How in PHP can I get the profile of a google user using the 0auth 2.0 API from Google?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, profile

on my website I set up a connection system with Google. The thing is, every day at midnight I would like to run a PHP script, which would retrieve the profiles of my users connected with Google, to compare with the database, and if it is different, then modify my database. The thing is, I don't know how to retrieve a user from an email. (ex: I want to retrieve the account of example@gmail.com). Does anyone know?